How to create a bridge interface using cloned MAC address from ethernet?
EDIT: this is probably a user-error
Strangely, after I setup my OPNsense, and IP's DHCP reservation on my PC, the issue hasn't cropped up since.
While I was testing out the VLAN's by creating tagged VLAN interfaces, I noticed that my Netplan's br0 getting deleted frequently.  I checked all of my YAML files and found the one that Network Manager created and it appears that there was a duplicate that could've been causing my problems.
All good now.

I created a netplan for the bridge network that matches with its default ethernet port:
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp7s0:
      match:
        macaddress: "d8:5e:d3:04:3d:59"
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false

  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      macaddress: "d8:5e:d3:04:3d:59"
      interfaces:
      - enp7s0
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 2
        priority: 0
        stp: true
      routes:
      - scope: "link"
        to: "default"

While it works, the issue, however, is that when I wake the computer, it takes a min for the network to establish.  Is there a proper way?

The easiest thing to try first: autosuspend / resume parameters in your netplan.
autosuspend: 1 on the ethernet, to enable automatic suspension.
resume: 1 to specify the bridge should resume first.

Alternatively:
You can use networkd-dispatcher to initialize the bridge network before the interface.
Create a new file:
sudo nano /etc/networkd-dispatcher/dispatcher.d/bridge-pre-init.sh
Add the following contents to the file and save.
#!/bin/bash

# Set up the bridge network before the interface is brought up
networkctl enable br0
networkctl start br0

Change mode to executable:
sudo chmod +x /etc/networkd-dispatcher/dispatcher.d/bridge-pre-init.sh

Reboot.Test the network connectivity.

Another option: Set up a static IPv4 address and have NetworkManager manage the bridge.
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

  ethernets:
    enp7s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.2/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]

  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.3/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
      interfaces:
      - enp7s0
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 2
        priority: 0
        stp: true

This sets a static IPv4 address of 192.168.1.2/24 on enp7s0, plus the gateway/DNS servers.br0 is configured static, 192.168.1.3/24, (same gateway/DNS as enp7s0).
Be sure to check the "Wake-On LAN" settings in the BIOS, also.
It could be that simple.
Still no luck?Even more info.

Strangely, after I setup my OPNsense, and IP's DHCP reservation on my PC, the issue hasn't cropped up since.
There was an issue with my Netplan's br0 getting deleted frequently, and I checked all of my YAML files and found the one that Network Manager created and it appears that there was a duplicate that could've been causing my problems (thought it was created because I had this computer on WiFi for a while).
All good now.

Good stuff.  When it comes to that kind of thing, it's par for the course.  You just never know.  It could be a simple 1, not a 0, all the way to you may have to go static,  To, "it was a BIOS setting the whole time!?!".  They all happen, regularly.
